# Filter genbank files by the order of the species in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genbank

Im making a local data base of genbank files of 456 sequences of FOXP2 genes of mammals, this sequences came off form a blastn. Im using the "ape" R package in order to explore the genbank files, I used the read.genbank function with the 456 IDs and store the result on an object. I want to subset the rodents from all this sequences of mammals however the only attributes that the object have are names(IDs), class, description and species. Is there a way I can filter my files in order to get only the rodents?

Comment: What are the species names you want to keep? And can you show the output of `str(data)` for your data?

Comment: I need information about the Order of all the 456 IDs, problem is that the read.Genbank function only gave me species name. > str(seqsmammals)
List of 307
 $ XM_017321341: raw [1:6492] 48 18 48 48 ...
  [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "DNAbin"
 - attr(*, "description")= chr [1:307] "XM_017321341.1 PREDICTED: Mus musculus transcript variant X1" "variant 3" "variant 1" "BC058960.1 Mus musculus forkhead box P2, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:66838 IMAGE:6811877), complete cds" ...
 - attr(*, "species")= chr [1:307] "Mus_musculus" "Mus_musculus" "Mus_musculus" "Mus_musculus" ...

Comment: As I dont necessarily need to do both things on the same process, I was thinking about doing a table with the information of the Orders, I have a big genbank file with the 456 files on it in .txt, was thinking about extracting the orders by using grep.